# Scaffolding in .Net Core with Multiple Projects in Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have created an .Net Core MVC6 application targeting net461.  I have used a project structure I am very familiar with in which I place the data, model, and service classes in separate class library projects and the Web project references these.

When I attempt to scaffold a controller I receive an error that multiple matching types exist for the model I am scaffolding.

If I move all code to a single project, scaffolding is successful.  If I move the context to Web project and leave the model in a separate project, I receive an error the NO matching types were found.

Has anyone else seen this same issue?  Is there a workaround to still use this type of architecture?

**Update**

I started another project and always get this issue.  I get this error when only using 1 extra project for the models. Attached is the error I recieve.

[Scaffolding Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9uzt.png)

**Update 2**

When the context and model are in the same project I receive this error.

[Error editing dbContext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAWXG.png)

Comment: Hi,not sure if related but probably not ,but I am having issues in calling classes located in a different project in same solution.Solution compiles but cannot call class as main project even though is referenced call see this class/assembly.Have  you had the same issue? I put a project on github https://github.com/developer9969/ProjToProjReference.

Comment: @developer9969 Do you have resharper? If so, do you have build errors or just intellisense? Resharper does not fully support rc2 yet.  https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/05/27/resharper-ultimate-2016-2-eap-kicks-off/

Comment: yes I have resharper the solution compiles but if I try to call the class on a project within solutions I can't because visual studio doesn't show me the new class in either in the using statements or by instantiating it.

Comment: yes you are right disabled resharper and my intellisense  now works.It fooled me for all weekend.GRRRRRR.THANKS!

Comment: @developer9969 On a side note I didn't fully disable Resharper.  I just added the Views folder to the ignore list in Resharper => Options => Code Inspection => Settings => Elements to skip.  This seems to work fine and lets me use other Resharper features such as conver to LINQ and etc.

Comment: Still have not found a solution for my problem.  For now I have resorted to keeping all files in one solution.  I have recreated my problem on several machines so I don't believe I am the only one seeing this behavior.  Can someone confirm this is a bug?

Answer (score 10):

Cannot post a comment, so I've to write an answer instead. I also had the same issue and opened it on Scaffolding github repository. Here's the [response](https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/249):

> currently there is an issue with scaffolding, that it doesn't support
>   model classes outside of the current project properly.
>
> As a workaround, you can add the model temporarily to your web project
>   and then move it to the BLL/ DAL projects after scaffolding.

Plus they also opened [this issue as a bug](https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/251), quoting:

> Scaffolding fails if model class is in a dependency (project/ library)
>   of the project on which scaffolding is being run. #251
>
> Project A has a dependeny on Project B.  Project B has model class  If
>   you try to run scaffolding on Project A by using model class from
>   Project B, it fails with the below error:  No model type returned for
>   type:

Hence, as of RC2, this is a bug in scaffolding tooling.

Comment: Thank you. This is an example of a well researched answer as well as a workaround